# Get list of all exported components in file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a lot of minor components:

```
export const A = () => {...}     
export const B = () => {...}
...
export default [A, B, ...];
```

After adding another component to the file, I might forget to add it to the `export default [...]`. By now you should see what the problem is.
How should I resolve this issue? Is it maybe possible to define a list that includes all exported functions?

---

I want to be able to iterate over all components in other files. Hence why it has to be a list they are grouped into.

Comment: Well, another file can do `import * as foo from 'someFile'`, then use `foo.A` and `foo.B`, etc. Does that suffice?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting you create an additional file who's job is to group the components, i'm saying in the file where you're already importing the array, could you use `import *` instead?

Comment: @NicholasTower I don't think that would work for me since I want to iterate over all components imported. That's why I `export default` in the form of a list

Comment: Does this file export additional things which aren't components? If so, then yeah, `import *` wouldn't really work because you'd have a tough time distinguishing which ones to include and which ones not to. But if you want to iterate over all of the exports, `import *` will work for that. It's in the form of an object, not an array, but `Object.values(foo)` will give you the array.

Comment: @NicholasTower That is great! That'll do.

Answer (score 1):

origin file `src/foo.js`:

```
export const A = () => { ... };
export const B = () => { ... };
export const C = () => { ... };
```

Create an `src/index.js` as following:

```js
import foos from './foo';
const allComponents = Object.values(foos);
export default allComponents;
```

---

From another file we'd:

```js
import foos from 'src/foo';

foos[0]() // A()
foos[1]() // B()
...
```

**EDIT**: fixed the example code, needs to use `values()` not `keys()`, my bad

Comment: Downside: it seems overkill to introduce an additional file for the sole purpose of grouping the exported components into a list.

Comment: I'd just add manually to the `default` array. This is an automatic way so you won't forget any exported member

Answer (score 1):

With some minor modifications, you can use `import *`. This gives you all of the named exports of a file, wrapped up into an object. If, for example, your old code was doing this:

```
import allComponents from 'someFile'

allComponents.forEach(component => {
  // do something with the component
})
```

... instead do this:

```
import * as allComponents from 'someFile'

Object.values(allComponents).forEach(component => {
  // do something with the component
})
```

As new exports are added to the file, this import statement will pull them in automatically, and so the default export array shouldn't be needed anymore.